# How to read Array from JSON on backend

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Frontend sends JSON in such structure:

```
{
    "orderElement":
        [
            {
            "product": 
              {
               "id" : 3,
               "name" : "product1",
               "description" : "desc1",
               "category": 
                       { 
                        "id":2, 
                       "name" : "cat1"
                       },
               "price" : 112},
               "quantity" : 1
            },
            {
            "product": 
              {
               "id" : 4,
               "name" : "product2",
               "description" : "desc2",
               "category":                            
                       {
                       "id" : 3, 
                       "name" : "cat2"
                       },
                price" : 353
              },
               "quantity" : 1
            }
        ],
      "user" 
           {
            "id" : 109,
            "lastName" : "a",
            "firstName" : "a",
            //rest of parameters
           }
 }
```

console.log used on ts component returns full JSON containing all that data.

Yet, when this is being send to backend orderElement is being null'ed (User is being sent OK, OrderPlaceTime is filled on server side):

```
@Component
public class OrderConverter implements Converter<Order, OrderDTO> {

    @Override
    public Order convertToEntity(OrderDTO dto) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setId(dto.getId()); //ok
        order.setUser(dto.getUser()); //ok
        order.setOrderPlaceTime(now()); //ok
        order.setOrderElements(dto.getOrderElements()); <--- this is null, set sets null in order
        return order;
    }
```

So main questions are:

1) Why this is being null although it is being send from frontend correctly

2) If there is any particular way needed to parse array inside of JSON, how to do it in this case?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably because your JSON property is named `orderElement`, whereas your DTO property is named `orderElements`.

Comment: lol. brilliant, that helped. thank you! lesson learned :)

Comment: @Doomsay please provide it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as JB Nizet said:

Probably because your JSON property is named orderElement, whereas your DTO property is named orderElements.

changing "orderElement" to "orderElement**s**" solved the issue.

Thank you!